# Not able to fit model in tensorflow on mac M1 pro

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, apple-m1

I have been able to install a tensorflow kernel and import related packages (keras etc.)

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a simple linear regression model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_train = [2, 4, 6, 8]

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

I'm getting the following error (only when including the last line of code):

```
Epoch 1/10
2023-01-18 15:08:48.858121: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
2023-01-18 15:08:48.966479: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x165b6cbb0
2023-01-18 15:08:48.966508: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x165b6cbb0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 12
      9 x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
     10 y_train = [2, 4, 6, 8]
---> 12 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:

NotFoundError: Graph execution error:
...
    File "/Users/Vetle/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1211, in apply_grad_to_update_var
      return self._update_step_xla(grad, var, id(self._var_key(var)))
Node: 'StatefulPartitionedCall_1'
could not find registered platform with id: 0x165b6cbb0
```

I am able to print this information, which makes things look good:

Python Platform: macOS-13.0-arm64-arm-64bit
Tensor Flow Version: 2.11.0
Keras Version: 2.11.0

Python 3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:25:29) [Clang 14.0.6 ]
Pandas 1.5.2
Scikit-Learn 1.2.0
GPU is available

Comment: Hi @raykenz, Could you please try installing Tensorflow again in your system by following the [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) official page or this [link](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) as I am not getting when I tried running the same code in the same configuration. Please have a look at this replicated code [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/176810033102cf14f1883679c897852d/75160576.ipynb) for your reference. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade your tensorflow-macos and tensorflow-metal version to 2.9 and 0.5.0

[Article](https://medium.com/@yningz/how-to-install-and-actually-run-with-tensorflow-on-m1-m2-mac-with-metal-plugin-in-3-steps-81341d0a9363)